# Convert Row Data Into Column

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper, pivot-table

```
AssetName   Generation_Qtr  Cum_Actual_Gen
10001         2007 Q 2           0
2             2007 Q 3           182.21
10001         2007 Q 3           0
2             2007 Q 4           1064.49
10001         2007 Q 4            0
2             2008 Q 1           1937.18
3             2008 Q 1           1498.21
4             2008 Q 1           1291
```

I am trying to write pivot query to convert rows to columns such that i will get the below output

```
assetname   2007 q 1    2007 q 2   2007 q 3    2007 q 4
1001                     1937.18   1937.18     1937.18
2                        1937.18   182.21      1064.49   
3           1498.21
4           1291
```

Is there any better approach.
I am dealing with huge volume of data, close to 500 000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL to Pivot the data. Example below

```
declare @cols as varchar(100)
declare @sql as varchar(1000)

set @cols = ''
set @sql = ''

select @cols  = @cols + case when @cols = '' then '[' else ', [' end + Generation_Qtr + ']'
FROM dbo.MyData
group by Generation_Qtr
order by Generation_Qtr

select @Sql = 'SELECT *
FROM (
    select AssetName,   Generation_Qtr,  Cum_Actual_Gen 
    FROM dbo.MyData
) as s
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(Cum_Actual_Gen )
    FOR Generation_Qtr IN (' + @Cols + ')
)AS p'

exec(@Sql)
```